# Trying to get started on a script in PHP or Shell that will run in a CronJob

Tags: php, bash, shell, cron

I am in a dilemma and I am not quite sure where to start.
Let me know if you need more information.

I want to run a cronjob that occurs every weekday at 8:01 in the morning. 
I think I have that correct:
`1 8 * * 1,2,3,4,5 /path/to/script` <--(.php or .sh).

So actually creating the cronjob doesn't seem to be the issue. It's the data I want to pull. I basically need this information in text to be sent out in an email at 8:01.

1. Ping a website and to see if its up and running, if it is, then echo "website is up"
2. Ping the  Database to see if its up and running, if it is, then echo "database is up"
3. I need the details when I  “ls –ltr” under the directory "LOG" and maybe somehow provide an error message if the newly modified
   date on certain logs doesn’t equal the current date.
4. I need any error message from when I run “ff -s error -i -t .log” to be printed in the email, and if there are no errors, specify there were no
   errors.
5. I need to run ‘ls –ltr” in the directory "AV", and provide an error message if the last modified date on the zip file doesn’t
   equal the current date (similar to the LOG)
6. I need to run a SQL Statement (A Select Count) on a few things, and I would need that data to be in it.

This seems all very feasible to me, I just need to know the foundation on starting the script.

Can anyone offer any suggestions on a good starting point? Or even references to look upon?

Comment: I would do this in a bash script. Just take it step by step. Figure out how to ping a website. Figure out how to test if that ping worked. Figure out how to echo something to the screen (or a file to email when the script is done). Figure out how to ping the database. etc... This question, as is, is much to broad. Get to work and when you get stuck, as specifically about the thing you are stuck on.

Comment: Sounds like a plan, I will look and see how to do each step on google. When I finish Ill revisit this question with my possible solution. Im hoping after that, the people of StackOverflow won't chew me up too bad haha.